# Oracle SQL Конкатенация каждой строки с каждой

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть две таблицы:

**table1**

```
id | name_t1
1  | aaa1
2  | aaa2
3  | aaa3
```

**table2**

```
id | name_t2
1  | bbb1
2  | bbb2
3  | bbb3
```

Что то не могу сообразить как сделать конечный запрос, чтобы объединить каждую строчку с каждой?

**view**

```
id | name_t1+name_t2
1  | aaa1bbb1
2  | aaa1bbb2
3  | aaa1bbb3
4  | aaa2bbb1
5  | aaa2bbb2
6  | aaa2bbb3
7  | aaa3bbb1
8  | aaa3bbb2
9  | aaa3bbb3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id * 3 + t2.id - 3 AS id
     , t1.name_t1 || t2.name_t2 AS name_t1_t2
FROM table1, table2
```

Comment: Что то аж стыдно стало)))) Спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

*Каждую с каждой* = *cross join*. Например:

```
create table t1 as select rownum  id, 'aaa'||rownum name from xmlTable ('1 to 3');
create table t2 as select id, 'bbb'||id name from t1;

select rownum id, t1.name||t2.name name
from t1 cross join t2
;

        ID NAME     
---------- ----------
         1 aaa1bbb1  
         2 aaa1bbb2  
         3 aaa1bbb3  
         4 aaa2bbb1  
         5 aaa2bbb2  
         6 aaa2bbb3  
         7 aaa3bbb1  
         8 aaa3bbb2  
         9 aaa3bbb3
```